# WebSocket Reverse Proxy with Apache 2 or Nginx Configuration not working

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, websocket, stomp, apache2.4

I am trying to set up reverse proxy for WebSocket End Point. WebSocket end point is written in Spring Boot. The end point exposed uses Stomp over WebSocket protocol.

No request is received when the reverse proxy URL is used. Calling the End Point Directly from Angular Application works fine.

Tried following configurations but none of them worked.

Apache ***2.4***

#1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  
  ProxyPass "/TestWebApp/ws/" "ws://localhost:28081/TestWebApp/ws/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/TestWebApp/ws/" "ws://localhost:28081/TestWebApp/ws/"
</VirtualHost>
```

or

#2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) ws://localhost:28081/TestWebApp/ws/ [P,L]
    
</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx ***1.21.6***

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }
     
    upstream websocket {
        server 127.0.0.1:28081;
    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        
        set $url "127.0.0.1:28081";

             
        location /TestWebApp/ws/ {
             proxy_pass $url;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
          }
        
    }
}
```

Following error is seen on the browser console.

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/TestWebApp/ws/' failed:

URL used in the Angular Client Application is as follows

ws://localhost/TestWebApp/ws/'

However, if the direct URL (without reverse proxy) is used, then connection is successful

Direct URL ->  ws://localhost:28081/TestWebApp/ws/'

Using below code in the angular application

```
connect() {
    
   //const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:28081/TestWebApp/ws');
  const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/TestWebApp/ws/');
    const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.debug = null;
    return stompClient;
}
  
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let ws = this.connect();
    ws.connect({}, (frame) => {
      this.socketConnected = true;
      alert("connected")
      ws.subscribe('/errors', (message) => {
        //this.toast.error(message.body);
        this.socketConnected = false;

      });
      ws.subscribe('/user/algoJobQueue/jobStatus', (message) => {
        console.log("got message");
      });
    })
}
```

I can see in the Spring boot application logs that the request is not flowing to the Spring boot application from Apache2 or Nginx. Thus, I am suspecting there is a configuration miss.

**Out of Apache 2 or Nginx, any one configuration fix is okay for me. I can use any of these two servers;**

Comment: have you "enabled" websockets in nginx/apache?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.dmain.name;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev_localhost.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```